# Why are Typescript Declarations Generated With References?

Tags: typescript

I have a project that is written in typescript (the **lib** project) and consumed by another project written in typescript (the **app** project). The lib project compiles to a single js file and generates a declarations file. Everything works as expected but the generated declarations file contains this reference at the top-

```
/// <reference path="typings/index.d.ts" />
```

In the lib project there is a `typings` directory next to the `tsconfig.json` but it's only needed for the lib project. It should not be included as a reference in the declarations file. Here is my tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "proj-lib.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./js/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Why does my declarations file contain references?

**Temporary Solution**

Using `gulp-regex-replace` to remove references from declaration files.

```
tsResult.dts
            .pipe(replace({regex: /\/\/\/\s*<reference[^>]+>\s*/g, replace: ''})) // remove references in declaration file
            .pipe(gulp.dest(target));
```

This is not ideal. I hope there is a tsc solution.

Answer (score 0):

check the docs for typescript compiler options :)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

--declaration  boolean  (default)false  Generates corresponding ‘.d.ts’ file.

you only need references for typings (.d.ts files)

If you turn if off in your tsconfig (option line 3) it should go away.

Cheers

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I want `d.ts` files, but I don't want references in those generated files.